# updating main display when user inputs data into "edit specs" display

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, auto-update

I have two tkinter gui displays. the first display (we will call 'main display') takes data from my database (my database has 4 rows, but I only display 3 of them... the 4th is just an auto incremented id) and displays the newest data element in each of my 3 rows. My other display (we will call 'edit specs display') opens through clicking the 'edit specs' button on my main display window... the edit specs display has 3 entry widgets along with a submit button. when the user enters data into the entries and clicks submit, their entries will be stored in the appropriate rows in my database and then close the 'edit specs' display window.

My problem that I am facing is I cannot figure out a way to automatically update my main display screen once the user submits new data to my database.

for example, if my main display is currently showing values of 2,4,6 from my database, and a user uses the edit specs display and submits 3,5,7 to the database, I would have to close the code out and re-run it to show the 3,5,7 on the main display.

My goal is to when the user submits data through the edit specs screen, my main display screen will automatically "update" and display the new  user data

I cannot post my code now, but will later today. is their any ideas before hand that might accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: Have you thought about periodically checking values from the main program for an update to the database? This is if you cannot trigger a update from the area which the user updates the database.

Comment: how would you do that in code? I have tried a gui.update() function, but have had no luck with this...